# How do I overwrite data with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6))
#>   a b
#> 1 1 4
#> 2 2 5
#> 3 3 6
```

I figured out how to overwrite data with base R. Maybe that was day 1 of learning R.

```
df[2:3, 2] <- c(50, 60)
#>   a b
#> 1 1 4
#> 2 2 50
#> 3 3 60
```

I never found an easy way to do it with dplyr. How do I overwrite data with the pipe `%>%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `replace` within `mutate`.  If we can use the column names, i.e. 'b', `replace` the 'b' by specifying the `list` parameter in `replace` with the index of rows and the `values` as a `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(b = replace(b, 2:3, c(50, 60)))
#   a  b
#1 1  4
#2 2 50
#3 3 60
```

---

Or specify the index of columns in `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(2, replace, list = 2:3, values = c(50, 60))
```

Comment: @JasonHunter. I think there is a function in one of those packages where you give the row and column index to update the cell.  Sorry, forgot that function/package name.